# "Guess My Number" game with only allow 3 guesses from user

Tags: java, loops

I've created many different types of method in my coding as my task requires to, so I faced some problems that I'm trying to incorporate loops that allow only 3 guesses from the user.  After each round, the user has the option of whether to continue playing or to stop. How should I implement that? Also, any mistakes in my coding? Thank you in advanced!

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class GuessmyGame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random random = new Random();
      int number = random.nextInt(100)+1;
      
      printInstruction();
      int guess = in.nextInt();
      guessNum(number, guess);
      numberOfTries(guessNum);
    }
    
    public static void printInstruction(){
      System.out.println(" I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100."); 
      System.out.println(" Can you guess what it is? ");
      System.out.println(" Type a number : ");
    }
    
    public static void guessNum(int number, int guess){
      if (number == guess){
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You got it right.");
      }
      else if(number > guess){
        System.out.println("Your guess is too low.");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        guess = in.nextInt();   
        System.out.println("Your guess is: "+guess);
        guessNum(number, guess);
      } 
      else{
        System.out.println( "Your guess is too high.");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        guess = in.nextInt();   
        System.out.println("Your guess is: "+guess);
        guessNum(number, guess);
   }
   }
    public static void numberOfTries(int guessNum){
      Random random = new Random();
      int number = random.nextInt(100)+1;
      for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        System.out.println("Out of guesses!");
        System.out.println("The number was " + number);
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: By each round do you mean every 3 attempts?

Comment: The for loop prints out the same number 3 times, what is it's purpose? Is the user making 3 attempts for the same number?

Comment: I figured, I can't really use the code provided and update it cause it has a number of bugs. I have given general blueprint for implementation in my answer.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop and add a `boolean` condition.. let's call it `canContinue`. You'll also need to keep track of how many times the user has attempted to guess, let's say it's called `attemptCount` as well as the correctness of the user's latest guess (`correctGuess`).

When `attemptCount` is 3 or `correctGuess` is true, prompt the user if they want to continue. If their answer suggests they don't want to continue, set `canContinue` to false, which causes the exit the loop and complete. Otherwise, reset `attemptCount` (to 0 presumably to allow another 3 attempts). The code that follows highlights the requested logic. since it's clear the code provided in the question has many bugs.

```
var promptToRetry = false;

while (canContinue) {
  if (correctGuess) {
    // Let user know their guess was correct
    promptToRetry = true;
  }

  if (attemptCount > 2) {
    // Let user know they didn't get the right number
    promptToRetry = true;
  }

  if (promptToRetry) {
    boolean wantsToTryAgain = PromptUserToTryAgain(); //Code returning bool which prompts user if they want to try again (need to implement)
    
    if (wantsToTryAgain) {
      attemptCount = 0; //Resets attempt counter
      correctGuess = false; //Resets the guess
      promptToRetry = false;
    } else {
      canContinue = false; //Causes loop to exit
    }    
  }

  ...

  }
}
```